# Can not map one to one relationship in models

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I should relate Order with Invoice in one-to-one relationship but I am having the following error

```
Unknown mappedBy in com.example.task.model.Order.invoice referenced property unknown: com.example.task.model.Invoice.Invoice
```

Order model:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Order")
public class Order{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Column(nullable = true)
    private LocalDate date;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "Order")
    @JoinColumn(name = "order_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Invoice invoice;

    @OneToMany(targetEntity = Detail.class, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "order_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private List<Detail> details;
```

and Invoice model

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Invoice")
public class Invoice {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Order order;

    @OneToMany(targetEntity = Payment.class, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "inv_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private List<Payment> payments;

    @Column(nullable = true, precision = 8, scale = 2)
    private BigDecimal amount;

    @Column(nullable = true)
    private LocalDate issued;

    @Column(nullable = true)
    private LocalDate due;
```

Even if I change vice versa I having same error.

Comment: "order" not "Order"

Answer (score 1):

update this lines

```
@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "invoice_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
private Invoice invoice;

@OneToOne(mappedBy = "invoice")
private Order order;
```

Answer (score 1):

mappedBy attribute is mistyped.

Use mappedBy = "order" O lowercase